# ERROR in flutter: widget_test.dart cannot detect MyApp()

Tags: flutter-test

Being a total beginner I am trying out various flutter feature and I am stuck at running the main.dart due to errors in the widget_test.dart file. 
Please point out if the error is due to some other reason.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 void main(){
   var app = MaterialApp(
     title: 'FlutterApp',
     debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true,
     theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.black12,
        accentColor: Colors.orange,
     ),
     home: Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
         title: Text('Stateless'),
         backgroundColor: Colors.black,
         ),
   ),
   );
   runApp(app);
 }
```

**widget_test.dart**

```
// This is a basic Flutter widget test.
//
// To perform an interaction with a widget in your test, use the WidgetTester
// utility that Flutter provides. For example, you can send tap and scroll
// gestures. You can also use WidgetTester to find child widgets in the widget
// tree, read text, and verify that the values of widget properties are correct.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

import 'package:stateless/main.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('Counter increments smoke test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Build our app and trigger a frame.
    await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp()); //error over here

    // Verify that our counter starts at 0.
    expect(find.text('0'), findsOneWidget);
    expect(find.text('1'), findsNothing);

    // Tap the '+' icon and trigger a frame.
    await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.add));
    await tester.pump();

    // Verify that our counter has incremented.
    expect(find.text('0'), findsNothing);
    expect(find.text('1'), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

*This is my very first question and I a very sorry if I couldn't place the question in a proper way*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It would be better if you also told us the error message you got. However, from what I see, there is no MyApp defined in widget_test.dart.

You can define a MyApp widget in another file and then import it in your widget_test.dart.

An example would be:

another_file.dart

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
     title: 'FlutterApp',
     debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true,
     theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.black12,
        accentColor: Colors.orange,
     ),
     home: Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
         title: Text('Stateless'),
         backgroundColor: Colors.black,
         ),
   ),);
  }
}
```

widget_test.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

import 'package:stateless/another_file.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('My test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Build our app and trigger a frame.
    await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It did work. But after analysing the code and error I found out that the error was in this line :                 primaryColor: Colors.black12. Colors.black12 is not supported for some reason unknown to me.

Comment: Did you import material.dart ?

Comment: in my case i used the same solution and after i rename the another file to main again and it work it seems it is a IDE bug

Answer (score 3):

It's simple, you can just replace MyApp name with your class name in widget_test.dart file.

eg. replace MyApp with app (in your case) in widget_test.dart file

Answer (score 2):

I just figured out, the solution is just putting in your actual Stateful Widget name instead of the default 'MyApp' given by the default Tap Counter app!

Comment: looking long time for me to find this answer.. this never mentioned clearly in the doc if i'm not mistaken.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After you create a file named `another_file.dart`

You must add:

```
import '../test/another_file.dart';
```

in  `widget_test.dart`

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

At top of your `pubspec.yaml` make sure to verify the name of your project is a match with the name of the imported package listed in your import statement of the test widget.

After you verify this information run `flutter pub get` to sync the dependencies again.

In my case this resolved the improper name resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Your App name is MaterialApp in the main.dart file so as in widget_test.dart file change the MyApp name to MaterialApp as simple as that.

I'am also new to flutter but solving these kind of small problem's gives me a heads up, instead of giving solutions which are a little confusing to follow.

Comment: MaterialApp is the widget provided by the flutter framework. Creating that in the test will only test the framework instead of the app.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue but turns out it was because I was using an older version.

doing `flutter upgrade` or `fluter upgrade --force` will update your flutter version and it shouldn't show the problem anymore

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
flutter packages get
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score -2):

Just remove all lines in widget_test.dart file. Empty it..
It is used for testing widgets (not necessary)......

Comment: How exactly does deleting what needs to be solved solve the problem? Please read [answer]!

Comment: just empty it, it used for testing(not optional)