# Flutter tests - Having two Integration tests in a same group ()

Tags: flutter, testing, integration-testing, android-testing, flutter-test

I'm trying to run two tests in a same group in one test file.
If I split them into two separate test files, they are working fine.
But if I add them in a group, the 2nd test fail with the error saying *"TypeAdapter is already registered for the given id"*.

My app uses HiveDB and it sets up Hive boxes in the `main.dart` before launching the App. I understand that the 2nd test is also trying the same and fails because the setup is already done.

I followed [this doc](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction#5-run-the-integration-test) to setup and write integration tests.

Most of the youtube tutorials, medium articles, and other online resources explain so well on how to run one single test in a test file and they're outdated. I never found a resource having two tests in the same file yet.

- Here's my `main.dart`

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await HiveDB.setup();
  runApp(App());
}
```

- test_driver/integration_test.dart

```dart
import 'package:integration_test/integration_test_driver.dart';

Future<void> main() => integrationDriver();
```

- test/app_test.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:integration_test/integration_test.dart';

import 'package:integrationtestdemo/main.dart' as app;

void main() {
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

   group('Home screen tests', () {
    tearDown(() async {
      print("TearDown() -- called");
      await HiveDB.close();
    });

    testWidgets('Scenario # - loreum ipsum ...', (tester) async {
      // ARRANGE
      await app.main();
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      // ACT

      // ASSERT
      expect(1 + 3, 4);
    });

    testWidgets('Scenario #2', (tester) async {
      // ARRANGE
      await app.main();
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      // ACT

      // ASSERT
      expect(2 + 2, 4);
    });
  });
}
```

- The command I use to execute tests:

```
flutter drive --driver=.\test_driver\integration_test.dart --target=.\test\app_test.dart
```

- Error I get:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞═════════════════
The following HiveError was thrown running a test:
There is already a TypeAdapter for typeId 1.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      TypeRegistryImpl.registerAdapter (package:hive/src/registry/type_registry_impl.dart:104:11)
#1      HiveDB.setup (package:occasionly/src/services/hive_db.dart:80:10)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Could someone please help me here? I'm stuck on this for a long time and couldn't figure out a way to isolate the state between tests?

Comment: I am also facing this issue, i wonder have you found any solution for this issue?

Comment: @DanielSeow  Unfortunately, No!  It seems the flutter team doesn't care much about writing integration tests!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a dirty trick to solve "TypeAdapter is already registered for the given id" this error

try to put it like this, and the error will not appear anymore

```
Hive.registerAdapter(YourAdapter(), override: true);
```

But I have no idea what is the possible impact could this argument do

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, but I found a workaround by referring to this [ERROR in flutter: widget_test.dart cannot detect MyApp()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505370/error-in-flutter-widget-test-dart-cannot-detect-myapp), you could try it.

```
testWidgets('Scenario #1', (tester) async {
      // ARRANGE
      await app.main();
      ...
});

testWidgets('Scenario #2', (tester) async {
      // ARRANGE
      await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing the solution which worked for me...

```
void main(
  setUpAll(() async {
  // Initialize Hive and clear boxes
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  await Hive.deleteFromDisk();
  });
  
  testWidgets('Scenario #1', (tester) async {
  // ARRANGE
  await app.main();
  ...
  });

  testWidgets('Scenario #2', (tester) async {
  // ARRANGE
  await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());
  });
)
```